# A permanent remove of a specific windows 10 update?

Tags: windows, updates

So I have this "Windows 1709" update,
I haven't installed this upgrade yet, I did install it a few months ago but it messed up the home screen and all of my games ran at very low FPS.
And it happened twice now, I reinstalled windows twice because of that.
I just need the 'windows update' to completely and permanently stop telling me to upgrade. I tried the "services" and the task schedule and a lot of other things but the solutions are not permanent. I want to completely remove the option to upgrade to a different windows version. cause they suck. Thanks for the help in advance.

(There's another post that I made about this topic and people did not understand my problem very well, So I decided to make a new post, I want the solution to be permanent please)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Pro or higher edition of Windows 10, you can configure local group policy to block System upgrade.

Open GPedit.msc, locate **Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Update**, and enable  "**Turn off the upgrade to the latest version of Windows through Windows Update**".

Also, this registry can also work for this:

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate*

Create a DWORD value called **DisableOSUpgrade** and set it to 1.